# How can I hide the directory name to the end user via .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url, https

How can I make this link(s)

```
http(with or without s)://(with or without www).puaction.com/articles/Top-7-Best-Pheromone-Colognes-for-Men
```

looks like this :

```
https://puaction.com/Top-7-Best-Pheromone-Colognes-for-Men
```

each folder inside articles directory will displayed without the article directory so...

```
http(with or without s)://(with or without www).puaction.com/articles/(any article)
```

will be (non www / https / article directory will not be displayed by the end user)

```
https://puaction.com/ {any article name}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+articles/([\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://puaction.com/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /articles/$1 [L]
```